# Service architecture using technologies which provide parallelism and high scalability

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, hdfs, apache-storm, scalability

I'm working on a booking system with a single RDBMS. This system has units (products) with several characteristics (attributes) like: location, size [m2], has sea view, has air conditioner…
On the top of that there is pricing with its prices for different periods e.g. 1/1/2018 – 1/4/2018 -> 30$ ... Also, there is capacity with its own periods 1/8/2017 – 1/6/2018… Availability which is the same as capacity.
Each price can have its own type: per person, per stay, per item… There are restrictions for different age groups, extra bed, …
We are talking about 100k potential units. The end user can make request to search all units in several countries, for two adults and children of 3 and 7 years, for period 1/1/2018 – 1/8/2018, where are 2 rooms with one king size bed and one single bed + one extra bed. Also, there can be other rules which are handled by rule engine.

In classical approach filtering would be done in several iterations, trying to eliminate as much as possible in each iteration. There could be done several tables with semi results which must be synchronized with every change when something has been changed through administration.

Recently I was reading about Hadoop and Storm which are highly scalable and provide parallelism. I was wondering if this kind of technology is suitable for solving described problem. Main idea is to write “one method” which validates each unit, if satisfies given filter search. Later this function is easy to extend with additional logic. Each cluster could take its own portion of the load. If there are 10 cluster, each of them could process 10k units.
In Cloudera tutorial there is a moment when with Sqoop, content from RDBMS has been transferred to HDFS. This process takes some time, so it seems it’s not a good approach to solve this problem. Given problem is highly deterministic and it requires to have immediate synchronization and to operates with fresh data. Maybe to use in some streaming service and to parallelly write into HDFS and RDBMS? Do you recommend some other technology like Storm?
What could be possible architecture, starting point, to satisfy all requirements to solve this problem.

Please point me into right direction if this problem is improper for the site.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the simple RDBMS? And why do you need a *streaming solution* like Storm when simply changing to a sharded RDBMS, or some other clustered NoSQL database would be more appropriate? (Hadoop is not a database, and you need to understand the patterns of it in order to have any improvements... e.g. You cannot simply dump your database into Hadoop and it works OOTB).

Comment: I read on many places that RDBMS aren't so easy for horizontal scalability. You mentioned clustered NoSQL and it looks like a good direction. Still I'm not so confident, reading about NoSQL, that is possible to make complex queries. I'd like to have an option to do some extra service work/filtering on the top of query result from the NoSQL, also in parallel and scalable way.

Comment: I've seen some pretty complex queries in Couchbase or Cassandra. Neo4j, OrientDB, or Arango offer property graphs rather than relational tables, so those are appropriate when you find yourself commonly joining tables across keys. If all you're looking for is simple filtering based on some rule engine, feel free to start with Hadoop and "partitioned" Hive tables, ideally stored in Parquet format. If you need any faster querying, HBase is an option... In the end, this all depends on how you want to access the data, then each database has its own set of challenges it tries to address